# Issue in redirecting back to our Site from sandbox test authorize net

Tags: authorize.net

After processing the payment, control is not directing back to our site(`x_relay_url`) from `https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll`.

The URL mentioned in the `x_relay_url` cannot be accessed directly it requires session id and other details to access it which was passed to Authorize net page using `merchantDefinedData` variables.

I checked the following [article](https://support.authorize.net/s/article/Why-Are-My-SIM-Relay-Response-Transactions-Timing-out-After-Submitting-the-Request) also but our URL seems to be fine and we checked our code there is nothing wrong in that.

I tried multiple URLs in "x_relay_url" but nothing seems to be working.

Any help is appreciated.

**Error Message:**

> An error occurred while trying to report this transaction to the
>   merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them of
>   the error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your
>   credit card.
>
> This transaction has been approved.
>
> It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you will receive the product or service.

Comment: What URL are you trying to hit? Is it localhost?

Comment: Also, do you think it is a good idea to implement SIM if it is going to be going away soon? All of this work will be for nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Authorize.net throwing an error when my relay response URL points to a CodeIgniter controller and not otherwise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650747/why-is-authorize-net-throwing-an-error-when-my-relay-response-url-points-to-a-co)